# SQLite - How to use it at terminal level & C++ application?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

i am new to sqlite and I just recently installed it. I am familar with mysql but I need to use sqlite as I am using it for a C++ application that I am going to create.

**Question 1:**

I type this at my command line terminal

```
root@ubuntu:/home/baoky/version1.2/Assignment 2# sqlite abeserver.db
```

then I saw this output

```
sqlite>
```

So i type .h and i see a list of help commands

But i wanna create a table

sqlite> .databases

```
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /home/baoky/version1.2/Assignment 2/abeserver.db          
1    temp             /var/tmp/sqlite_hjT3FEefcAHRPhn
```

in my main database

How do i execute this sql command at terminal level

```
CREATE TABLE abe_account (
  username TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  department TEXT,
  password TEXT
);
```

**Question 2:**

How do I insert record into the table abe_account using C++

**Question 3:**

How do I retrieve records from table abe_account and assign it to a string using C++

Sorry I tried google around and search around stack overflow, I am still confused with the usage, if its mysql, it would be much simple for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the sqlite terminal, you can just type SQL there, and it will be executed.

A typical cycle of work from your C++ code will look *something* like this:

```
sqlite3 * db;//database
sqlite3_stmt * stmt;//sql statement

sqlite3_open( "database.db", & db );//opening database

sqlite3_prepare( db, "SELECT something FROM something else;", -1, &stmt, NULL );//preparing the statement
sqlite3_step( stmt );//executing the statement

while( sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 0 ) )
{
char * str = (char *) sqlite3_column_text( stmt, 0 );///reading the 1st column of the result
//do your stuff
sqlite3_step( stmt );//moving to the next row of the result
}

sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
sqlite3_close(db);
```

You can easily google the functions to learn about their arguments and what they do in-detail.

Comment: what library i need to include to use this sqlite3 at C++

Comment: you'll need to `#include sqlite3.h`

Answer (score 2):

> Question 2:
>
> Question 3:

Let me google it for you, friend: [An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

Answer (score 1):

To create a new database, just connect to it:

```
$ sqlite3 your_database_file
```

This will create your database in the file `your_database_file`. If this file already exists, the command will open it.

Then you can execute `CREATE TABLE` or any other SQL.

Comment: How do i execute create table when i am inside sqlite>

Comment: I just tried, but I type show tables; or show databases; it doesn't work, how do i list all tables in my database

Comment: okay i manage to use .tables and .databases to perform the following, a bit different look and feel, but i start to get the hang of it, thanks for the help.